# Saddle point method

Tags: integration

I need to calculate the following integral

$$\int_0^\infty{ a \; b \; t^2 \; e^{-b t} e^{- a (1 - (1 + b t) e^{- b t}} \frac{a^{k - 1} (1 - (1 + b t) e^{- b t})^{k - 1}}{(k - 1)!}} dt$$
with $a = 890, b = 0.02178799631089532$, which exhibits a maximum and therefore can be calculated by the saddle point method for values of $k$ of let's say from $100$ to $300$, for values of $k$ greater than $a$ the integrad tends to zero. How can I calculate the integral using the saddle point method?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by taking out values and rearranging:
$$\int_0^\infty{ a \; b \; t^2 \; e^{-b t} e^{- a (1 - (1 + b t) e^{- b t}} \frac{a^{k - 1} (1 - (1 + b t) e^{- b t})^{k - 1}}{(k - 1)!}} dt=\frac{a^kb}{(k-1)!}\int_0^\infty t^2e^{-bt}e^{-a(1-(1+bt)e^{-bt})}\left[1-(1+bt)e^{-bt}\right]^{k-1}dt={\frac{a^k}{b^2(k-1)!}\int_0^\infty u^2e^{-u}e^{-a(1-(1+u)e^{-u})}\left[1-(1+u)e^{-u}\right]^{k-1}dt}$$